# Como selecionar CNPJ maior faturamento? - SQL -

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, pessoal!

Tenho um tabela de clientes com código de Grupo Economico e CNPJ, cada grupo economico possui mais de um registro, e cruzei com minha tabela de Faturamento e Endereço, até aqui tudo certo.

Eu queria pegar o endereço do CNPJ de maior faturamento e ter como resultado final apenas Código Grupo Economico e Endereço, sem mostrar o CNPJ e Faturamento, mas não consigo.

Depois de cruzar tentei o código abaixo, mas o resultado vem errado, o endereço não é do CNPJ de maior faturamento:

```
Select CodGrupo, NomeGrupo, First(CNPJ), Max(Fat), Cidade, UF
From tbl_EndFat 
Group By CodGrupo, NomeGrupo, Cidade, UF 
OrderBy max(fat)
```

Edit: Meu objetivo é que a consulta retorne o endereço do CNPJ de maior faturamento para cada grupo econômico.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Porquê o "`First(CNPJ)`"? O objetivo é apenas retornar o registo de maior faturamento?

Comment: Não, eu me expressei mal, o objetivo é retornar o endereço do CNPJ de maior faturamento para cada Grupo Econômico.

Comment: @AlanTeixeira Problema resolvido?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com sua pergunta eu fiz uma solução, você disse que quer o codigo economico e endereço da empresa com maior faturamento, porém duas empresas podem ter o maior faturamento, isso pode ser um problema, mas de acordo com sua pergunta isso não é um problema. Segue o código que poderá te ajudar, basicamente é recuperar apenas a(s) empresa(s) que tem o maior faturamento.

Se você quer só a empresa com maior faturamento o group by é desnecessário, ao meu ver.

```
Select CodGrupo, NomeGrupo, Cidade, UF
From tbl_EndFat 
where Fat = (select max(fat) from tbl_EndFat)
```

Comment: Supondo que NomeGrupo seja funcionalmente dependente de CodGrupo você precisa correlacionar o CodGrupo do subselect com o SELECT mais externo.

Comment: Olá amigo, gostei da sugestão, mas ela não se aplica. Eu não me expressei bem, na verdade eu preciso que saída me mostre o endereço do CNPJ de maior faturamento para cada Grupo Economico. 
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

> Meu objetivo é que a consulta retorne o endereço do CNPJ de maior
> faturamento para cada grupo econômico.

Avalie se o código sql a seguir retorna o que que necessita.

```
-- código #1
SELECT top (1) with ties 
       CodGrupo, NomeGrupo, CNPJ, Faturamento, Cidade, UF
  from ...
  order by rank() over (partition by CodGrupo
                        order by Faturamento desc);
```